# How to style a htmlspecialchars php variable

Tags: php, css

I want to make the **$result** and **$domain** red how to do that?

```
        case Transip_DomainService::AVAILABILITY_NOTFREE:
            $result = htmlspecialchars($domain);
        break;
```

Comment: Well then put a span around it and add a `style="color:red"` to the span

Comment: @RiggsFolly Yea but I have more options than 1 so if I change it in html is will always show red. I have 4 cases so I want 4 colors. and does span work in php?

Comment: PHP has ABSOLUTELY NO EFFECT of the color of your text on a web page! HTML and/or CSS is the only thing that will have any effect

Comment: @RiggsFolly I know but I want to style the php variable $domain in the code I showed. Is it possible to style it?

Comment: So without seeing as much code as would have been useful try `$result = '<span style="colur:red">' . htmlspecialchars($domain) . '</span>';`

Comment: Works! thanks dude.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So without seeing as much code as would have been useful try simply adding the span around your existing call to `htmlspecialchar()` like this.

```
$result = '<span style="colur:red">' . htmlspecialchars($domain) . '</span>';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can alter your php code little bit and add variable for class.

```
case Transip_DomainService::AVAILABILITY_NOTFREE:
        $result = htmlspecialchars($domain);
        $css = "red";
    break;
```

And then in in HTML add something like `<span style="color:<?php echo $css; ?>"><?php echo $result; ?></span>`